# How do I make sure my website does not get blocked at my office for "potential harmful content? Do I need to adjust settings?

Tags: url

I created a new website that it is blocked from my office admnis for "potential harmful content".
Is there a setting that I need to change? Do I need some sort of certificate or plugin installed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, with out knowing your site, we can not really tell you something useful, but if your admins consider that your site is not appropriate, you may ask them which policy are you failing and then fix it.

It may also be that they are blocking the ip of your site due to open relay problems, or spam, or any other similar situation, so again, better to ask them.

Comment: I've seen admins also block websites just because they know an employee owns it -- and therefore has the potential to put whatever he/she wants on it, perhaps distractions or a proxy or something. But agreed, without knowing the content of the site, we can't determine the reason.